# cfn-lint failing while validating Cloudformation templates

Tags: python-2.7, aws-cloudformation

I had cfn-lint as part of my Jenkins pipeline setup everytime a build has been triggered. It validates the CloudFormation templates on specified paths on the cloned repo. Everything was working fine but suddenly I started to get these error logs. Anyone know what is going on (Seems like a python related issue to me)?

```
15:54:07  Traceback (most recent call last):
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/bin/cfn-lint", line 11, in <module>
15:54:07      load_entry_point('cfn-lint==0.35.1', 'console_scripts', 'cfn-lint')()
15:54:07    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 487, in load_entry_point
15:54:07      return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
15:54:07    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2728, in load_entry_point
15:54:07      return ep.load()
15:54:07    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2346, in load
15:54:07      return self.resolve()
15:54:07    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2352, in resolve
15:54:07      module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnlint/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
15:54:07      from cfnlint.transform import Transform
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnlint/transform.py", line 9, in <module>
15:54:07      from samtranslator.parser import parser
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samtranslator/parser/parser.py", line 2, in <module>
15:54:07      from samtranslator.validator.validator import SamTemplateValidator
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samtranslator/validator/validator.py", line 3, in <module>
15:54:07      import jsonschema
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
15:54:07      from jsonschema._types import TypeChecker
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/_types.py", line 3, in <module>
15:54:07      from pyrsistent import pmap
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrsistent/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
15:54:07      from pyrsistent._pmap import pmap, m, PMap
15:54:07    File "/home/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrsistent/_pmap.py", line 98
15:54:07      ) from e
15:54:07           ^
15:54:07  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Am also seeing this issue and just started today. Don't think that the template itself matters as I see the issue executing `cfn-lint --version`

Comment: these look potentially related: https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/734
https://github.com/tobgu/pyrsistent/issues/208

Comment: Yeah. I have upgraded my python version to 3.7 after which this issue is no longer occurring. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also hit this issue starting today. It is was not related to the stack template itself as I was getting the issue when executing `cfn-lint --version`.

Downgrading `pyrsistent` and `cfn-lint` (which both had recent updates) to previous versions solved the issue:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall cfn-lint==0.35.0 pyrsistent==0.16.0
```

Comment: `cfn-lint` should not need to be downgraded. I think downgrading `pyrsistent` should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Could you try upgrading the Linter and SAM translator?

`pip install cfn-lint aws-sam-translator --upgrade`

And include the template if that doesn't help?